# Populating data with scrapy's item loader works in shell but not in spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following simple spider composed of three files. 
My goal is to use item loader correctly to populate the data I'm currently scrapping. 
The `pipeline.py`is a simple json file creator as explained in scrapy documentation.

`items.py`

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class FoodItem(scrapy.Item):
    brand = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=TakeFirst(),
        output_processor=Identity()
    )
    name = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=TakeFirst(),
        output_processor=Identity()
    )

    description = scrapy.Field(
        input_processor=TakeFirst(),
        output_processor=Identity()
    )

    last_updated = scrapy.Field()
```

`spider.py`

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Test'
    allowed_domains = ['zooplus.fr']    
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.zooplus.fr/shop/chats/aliments_specifiques_therapeutiques_chat/problemes_urinaires_renaux_chat/croquettes_therapeutiques_chat/595867',
    ]


    def parse_item(self, response):

        l = ItemLoader(item=PetfoodItem(),response=response)
        l.add_xpath('brand', '//*[@id="js-breadcrumb"]/li[4]/a/span/text()')
        l.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="js-product__detail"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h1/text()')
        l.add_xpath('description', '//*[@id="js-product__detail"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/meta/@content')
        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_value('last_updated', 'today')

        l.load_item()

        return l.load_item()
```

If I do it manually and copy exactly the code of the spider into the shell, I populate exactly what I want. Xpath are for sure right because it's already an hardcoded and functional spider which I want to refine using pipelines and item loader. I can't get where there is the obvious mistake. It looks pretty straightforward though. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `CrawlSpider` incorrectly.

If you want to crawl a single product just stick to original `Spider` base class:

* changes marked with `^`

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    #          ^^^^^^
    name = 'zooplus'
    allowed_domains = ['zooplus.fr']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.zooplus.fr/shop/chats/aliments_specifiques_therapeutiques_chat/problemes_urinaires_renaux_chat/croquettes_therapeutiques_chat/595867',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
    #   ^^^^^
        l = ItemLoader(item=dict(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('brand', '//*[@id="js-breadcrumb"]/li[4]/a/span/text()')
        l.add_xpath('name', '//*[@id="js-product__detail"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h1/text()')
        l.add_xpath('description', '//*[@id="js-product__detail"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/meta/@content')
        l.add_value('url', response.url)
        l.add_value('last_updated', 'today')
        return l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the `ItemLoader` written in the `spider.py`. In my opinion, maybe you can check you logfile.  @BoobaGump use  `CrawlSpider`, and `parse_item` that is different name as `parse`， which is right @Granitosaurus. The warning [Crawling Rules](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules)  is specified:

> Warning
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

When I use `ItemLoader`, I can see item in the log, but I don't get item in the shell.